# I have a launch command that works but only in the terminal - how can I get this command to work in Startup Applications?

Tags: startup-applications, system-tray

Today, after much searching, I found the command `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP= keepassx` which is supposed to work in "Startup Applications" on 12.04. So far, I've only managed to get it to work from the terminal. But after months of research this feels like leap forward to finally see the keepassx icon in the system-tray! So, I'd hate to give up now. Does anyone feel like helping me figure out how to get this command to work as the default way to start keepassx? Or as a Startup App?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Not sure if I should delete the question now or leave it with an answer for anyone else to use. I'll just answer and let the mods decide.

1. Open gedit and enter:
   'XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP= keepassx'
2. Save as a ".sh" file-type. Just remember where.
3. Right click on your .sh and select Properties, go to the Permissions tab - check the box next to "Execute".
4. In Startup Applications select Edit for KeepassX. In the Edit window next to "Command:" use the Browse button and select your .sh.
5. Once KeepassX opens in startup for the first time after these changes you'll need to go to settings and enable the system tray functions by checking the according boxes.

Note: The KeepassX setting "Minimize to tray instead of task bar" may be problematic since the panel/systray icon offers no option to show the KeepassX GUI. The icon offers the same two functions when right or left-clicking - Quit and lock. But as long as you have KeepassX set up and auto complete enabled everything works fine.